# Laravel 5.1 Catching FTP File not found exception

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I want to download a file using FTP with Laravel 5.1, and I want to check if the file exists in the remote folder.  I included `use Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Filesystem` but it fails to catch the exception with the following error:
**[Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException]

  p25082016.csv**
My code looks like this:

```
    private function getFile()
    {
        try {
       // CONNECT TO FTP AND GET THE FILE
        } catch (FileNotFoundException $exception)  {
        die('File: '.$filename.' error');
        }
        return 'File: '.$filename.' OK';

    }
```

Any help?

Comment: have you imported the exception as well? `use Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException`?

Comment: Hi @Björn, yes, I imported that exception you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

> All exceptions are handled by the App\Exceptions\Handler class
>   ....
>   The render method is responsible for converting a given exception into an HTTP response that should be sent back to the browser. By default, the exception is passed to the base class which generates a response for you. However, you are free to check the exception type or return your own custom response

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/errors#the-exception-handler